# facebook canvas apprequest, single request id instead of request_ids?

Tags: facebook, canvas, facebook-app-requests

When user accepts a (single) apprequest, the canvas is called with (plural) request_ids parameter.
Is there a way to get a single request_id for that particular request that was clicked?

To make things a bit more clear, some context.

Requests in question are invitations to use the app. Suppose user R has pending invites from user A (sent two weeks ago), user B (sent a minute ago, still visible in a different browser window) and user C (sent just now). User R sees a pop-up saying "user C sent you an invitation", clicks it, and gets redirected to the app canvas with request_ids=request-A,request-B,request-C.

Since R clicked something saying "user C sent ...", I want the canvas to show something related to request-C only. However, the canvas gets a list of three requests instead, and I can't tell which one of those three was clicked.

This looks like a typical use case to me, however it turns out to be unexpectedly difficult to implement. Unless I'm overlooking something, that is.